# Simple Bash script on macos creating unwanted infinite loop

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a bash script to concatenate the contents of all text files in a folder/sub-folders and output that to a text file:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} + >> output.txt
```

This is creating an infinite loop.

My test directory is set up like:
`~/desktop/Dir0/Dir1/Dir2`

I created 2 text files:

1. `~/desktop/Dir0/Dir1$ touch text1.txt && echo "Hello" >> text1.txt`
2. `~/desktop/Dir0/Dir1/Dir2$ touch text2.txt && echo "World" >> text2.txt`

and then ran the .sh from within Dir0

The script did not conclude and running `cat output.txt` listed a long file containing *Hello\nWorld\nHello\nWorld\nHello\nWorld...* infinitely.

Troubleshooting I have tried so far:

1. Tried the same script in a Mint vm and it worked fine.
2. I upgraded bash3.2 to 5.1.16, still looping
3. Reading/testing

Anyone have an idea what might be happening here?

Comment: If you call your output file "output.tmp" then rename it to "output.txt" after the `find` command is finished, you won't have a problem (e.g. `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} + > output.tmp && mv output.tmp output.txt`). The issue is that you are creating a ".txt" file ("output.txt") and that is then 'found' by your `find` command and added to "output.txt"; the recursion is coming from your creation of a filename which matches "*.txt". Does that make sense?

Comment: That does make sense. Thank you @jared_mamrot. Solved

Comment: Another way around this is to create output.txt in a directory not covered by find: `find . -name '*.txt' ... > ../output.txt`

Comment: or use `... -name '*.txt' ! -name 'output.txt' ...` or maybe `! -path './output.txt'

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way is to use `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' ! -name 'output.txt' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 cat > output.txt
```

- This finds all files ending in `.txt` and not named `output.txt`.
- Passes them null (\0) terminated to `xargs` in null termination mode (-0).
- Then `cat` is called with more than 1 argument per execution.
- Finally writing to the desired output file.